# Magento admin section editing customer details hangs in IE

Tags: admin, customer, javascript, magento-1.6

Customer details are not saved on Edit customer details in admin in IE. It hangs saying "Please wait". It works fine in other browsers. Attached is the screenshot in IE 8 compatibility mode.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://nevyan.blogspot.com/2008/12/easy-solve-ajax-c00ce514-error.html

Comment: Sorry new to Magento. Let me know where to make this change. Specifically to ajax calls.

Comment: Sorry I don't have much. I just googled the error code

Comment: thanks Marrius, the error appears in IE 8 compatibility mode. In IE 9 and above it just hangs 'Please wait'...

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be the issue shown on a blog post by [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/ie9_fix_for_magento)

If so the solution is to update the `head.phtml` of your theme to add the meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```